# blank window is opened when clicked on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to export the data to PDF using html2pdf. To start with i have written a simple example, when clicked on export button a new blank window is opened without any content exported to it, any suggestions?

Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/ruWKJBQiZ9QgUjxaBzbo?p=preview

html code:

```
 <div ng-controller="listController">
        <button ng-click="export()">export</button>
     <h3> Simple Test</h3>

  </div>
```

js code:

```
 app.controller("listController", ["$scope",
   function($scope) {

 $scope.export = function() {

     var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        var canvas = pdf.canvas;
        canvas.height = 72 * 11;
        canvas.width= 72 * 8.5;;
        // can also be document.body
        var html = '<html><body>Hello from JS file <strong> World</strong></body></html>';
        html2pdf(html, pdf, function(pdf) {
                pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
        });
   }
   }
 ]);
```

When user click on export button, the string assigned to `html` variable should be exported and display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to open a new windows, use:

```
pdf.output('datauri');
```

The `dataurinewwindow` specifically requests the PDF to open in a new window.

Full example:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("listController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {

    $scope.export = function() {

      var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
      var canvas = pdf.canvas;
      canvas.height = 72 * 11;
      canvas.width = 72 * 8.5;;
      // can also be document.body
      var html = '<html><body>Hello from JS file <strong> World</strong></body></html>';
      html2pdf(html, pdf, function(pdf) {
        pdf.output('dataurl');
      });
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: It is not supporting when the data is large to fit in only one page. Please find the demo https://plnkr.co/edit/E0xVpRhtMMyNqOd4d69P?p=preview. When clicked on export button, PDF is downloaded but only page1 data is shown the remaining data is not shown(it is not supporting with multiple pages). Any inputs would be helpful.@Fenton